# R Hash - get Key based on value

Tags: r, hash

```
H = hash()
H[["numbers"]] = c(1,2,3)
H[["alpha"]] = c("x","y","z")
H[["animals"]] = c("cat","dog")
```

Now i want to get "animals" using "cat".
get the key of the hash based on the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to iterate over a `hash` but if you convert the hash to list this becomes easy.

```
search <- 'cat'
H1 <- as.list(H)

Filter(function(x) any(search == x), H1)

#$animals
#[1] "cat" "dog"
```

To get the name :

```
names(Filter(function(x) any(search == x), H1))
#[1] "animals"
```

---

Other alternative methods :

```
names(H1)[sapply(H1, function(x) any(search == x))]
names(purrr::keep(H1, ~any(search == .x)))
names(purrr::discard(H1, ~all(search != .x)))
```

**data**

```
library(hash)
H = hash()
H[["numbers"]] = c(1,2,3)
H[["alpha"]] = c("x","y","z")
H[["animals"]] = c("cat","dog")
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps. I have converted it into a list and then used it for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `hash::invert`.

```
invert(H)[["cat"]]
[1] "animals"
```

This also works for multiple hashes with the same value.

```
H[["mammals"]] = c("cat","dog","human")
invert(H)[["cat"]]
[1] "animals" "mammals"
```

That being said, I agree with the other answers that this is an inefficient way t perform the task.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, a hash table is meant to provide fast/efficient lookups of *keys* to *values*, not the other way around.

An *inefficient* way of doing the reverse is to iterate over all keys to find the value and go from there:

```r
v <- NULL
for (k in ls(envir = H)) if ("cat" %in% H[[k]]) v <- k
v
# [1] "animals"
H[[v]]
# [1] "cat" "dog"
```

whereas a cache miss would look like:

```r
v <- NULL
for (k in ls(envir = H)) if ("kangaroo" %in% H[[k]]) v <- k
v
# NULL
```

If you want something *efficient*, though, I would think that (1) you're going to increase complexity, and (2) all writes would become less speedy. This would effectively have two hash tables, one mapping keys to values, and one matching each value to a key. One problem with this is that in a hash table, it is perfectly legal to have a value referenced by multiple keys, but there is no perfect reverse logic: while it is feasible to point to all candidate keys, there is not a 1-to-1 relationship.